# "Díjole" en lugar de "Le dijo"

Tags: gramática, verbos, expresiones

Estoy pensando introducir esta forma verbal en mis expresiones que la encuentro más a menudo en literatura de antaño y que me parece no solo poético, sino práctico en algunas situaciones.

Otro ejemplo: "Acercóse" en lugar de "Se acercó"

Mi pregunta es: Cuál es el nombre de esta forma verbal y, es válido usarla para cualquier verbo y expresión o hay alguna regla que limita su uso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Los pronombres que se escriben pospuestos al verbo y pegados a él se llaman *pronombres enclíticos*. Las reglas para su uso están [en el DPD](https://www.rae.es/dpd/pronombres%20personales%20%C3%A1tonos). En resumen:

- Los pronombres enclíticos se usan en el infinitivo, gerundio e imperativo afirmativo, pero no en el imperativo negativo:

  - No ha conseguido explicármelo
  - Estás contándome una historia
  - Muévete / No te muevas

  Con el infinitivo y gerundio, en muchos casos también se pueden usar pronombres proclíticos (separados y antes del verbo) si el infinitivo o gerundio forman parte de una perífrasis verbal ("Me estás contanto una historia").
- Los pronombres enclíticos no se suelen usar en formas del indicativo. Su uso en estos casos implica una intención arcaizante, y parece que es común en el noroeste de España:

  - Acercose a mí lentamente
- Los pronombres enclíticos no deben usarse en ningún caso con formas del subjuntivo o el participio:

  - He <del>cansádome</del> mucho (Me he cansado mucho)
  - Me gustaría que <del>dijérasmelo</del> (Me gustaría que me lo dijeras).

Comment: Hay algún motivo para poner tilde en "acercose"?

Comment: @geofisue Lo que pasa es que "acercó" y "se" son dos palabras distintas pero pegadas. La regla era mantener la tilde, sin embargo esta regla se relajó. Los que somos mayorcitos seguimos tildando a la antigua, yo lo hago. No sé si en la actualidad es una falta ortográfica.

Comment: @geofisue efectivamente, era un error mío.  Lo he corregido: *acercose* no lleva tilde.

Comment: Genial, gracias!. Y cierto, la forma negativa no encaja: "No me convenció" - "Convenciónome". Pues eso, no me convenció.

Comment: @Rodrigo gracias, no lo sabía. Ahora se tilda siguiendo las reglas de acentuación.

Comment: En efecto, en el noroeste de España es más común usar enclíticos en el modo indicativo por influencia del gallego, lengua en que son habituales.

Comment: ... o del asturiano :)